# Angular ng-click misses a lot of clicks

Tags: angularjs

In my board game angular application I use ng-click to trigger card replacement in such a way:

```
<div ng-repeat="card in hero.hand" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
<div class="thumbnail" role="button" ng-click="play(card.id)"> <!-- nearly half of mouse clicks not processed -->
    <center>
        <h4>{{card.type}}</h4>
    </center>
    <img class="painting" ng-src="../gamedata/units/views/{{card.type}}.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

The problem is that click event fires not on every real mouse click but approximately only on a half of real clicks (it varies). I must say that $scope.hero is not static and updated in background using $interval (it changes hero pointer to a new hero object periodically). I think the problem could be concerning this update or some ng-repeat and ng-click interference - other ng-click directives in my application work properly firing on every real mouse click:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary inline" ng-click="pass()">Pass</button> <!-- all mouse clicks are processed -->
```

What could be done to solve or avoid such a problem?

For more information I provide play (pass is identical) and update functions

```
    $scope.play = function(id) {
    if(!$scope.processingAction) {
        $scope.processingAction = true;
        $scope.action.type = "card";
        $scope.action.source = [id];
        $scope.action.aim = [];
        gameService.playerAction($scope.action, function() {
            $scope.action.type = "";
            $scope.action.source = [];
            $scope.action.aim = [];
            $scope.processingAction = false;
        },
        function(err) {
            $scope.action.source = [];
            $scope.processingAction = false;
            alert(err);
        });
    }
};
```

(All worked the same without $scope.processingAction, so it's not the flag problem)

```
var update = function() {
    $scope.state = gameService.getGame().state;
    if($scope.state) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.state.players.length; i++) {
            if($scope.state.players[i].nick === $scope.user.nickname) {
                $scope.hero = $scope.state.players[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
var updatePromise = $interval(update, 1000);
```

gameService.getGame() is non-blocking one.

Comment: Can you show your pass function

Answer (score 0):

ng-click expects an angular expression. Internally, angular is using the $parse service to evaluate the expression in ng-click="expression".

An angular expression is not the same as regular javascript code. $parse uses string parsing to interpret the expression and it restricts your access to variables, functions, and objects to just those which are properties of the $scope object, or properties of any $parent scope objects which happen to be available further up the prototypical inheritance chain.

So in theory you could gain access to globals like this:

```
$scope.window = window;
 $scope.pass= pass;
```

and then

```
ng-click="pass()"
```

Comment: pass is not a global function and I don't experience problems with it.

Comment: $scope.pass = function() { ... }

Comment: I have problems with the first code snippet, not the second one